# How to see Rust source code when debugging WebAssembly in a browser?

Tags: rust, source-maps, webassembly

I am testing a simple todo app in Rust using the [YEW framework](https://github.com/DenisKolodin/yew). When I get an error, the browser console (Devmode) shows JavaScript or assembler (I tried both Chrome and Firefox). How can I get the Rust code? Do I have to setup source maps somewhere?

Comment: Not sure if this kind of tool exists for now...

Comment: [Firefox Nightly's Javascript debugger now supports debugging and source maps for Rust compiled to WASM](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/7jvoj3/firefox_nightlys_javascript_debugger_now_supports/) from last year Mozilla All Hands Austin, but I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: [OMG `@FirefoxNightly's` JavaScript Debugger supports debugging & source maps for `@rustlang` in `#WebAssemby-compiled` web code!](https://twitter.com/slsoftworks/status/941400137921949696)‏
`@slsoftworks` 14 Dec 2017
afaict you just just emscripten (not the direct rustc wasm backend) and it just works. /cc `@yurydelendik` `@jasonlaster11 `@kripken`

Comment: This question was [cross-posted to the Rust user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-see-rust-source-code-when-debugging-webassembly-in-a-browser/17933?u=shepmaster).

Comment: The example in the OP's cross-posted question shows that it is already possible: the webpage [here](https://yurydelendik.github.io/old-man-sandbox/rust-wasm-hey/hey.html), source repo [here](https://github.com/yurydelendik/old-man-sandbox/tree/master/rust-wasm-hey).

Comment: See also the comments on [this issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/2389).

Answer (score 8):

To achieve this you’d need WebAssembly to support sourcemaps. This is something that is being considered for [future tooling](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/FAQ.md#will-webassembly-support-view-source-on-the-web), but I don’t think much progress has been made yet.

There is also an [open issue for Rust sourcemap support](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/46765)

Comment: In OPs [cross-posted question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-see-rust-source-code-when-debugging-webassembly-in-a-browser/17933?u=shepmaster), they claim that it's already possible.

Comment: Seems that the issue you linked has been closed. Relevant/related links: https://github.com/WebAssembly/debugging | https://medium.com/oasislabs/webassembly-debugging-bec0aa93f8c6 | https://github.com/rustwasm/team/issues/26

Answer (score 3):

This is possible now for C++. See [this post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2020). You need to [install this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cc%20%20-devtools-support-dwa/pdcpmagijalfljmkmjngeonclgbbannb) and pass `-g` to generate debug info when compiling the C++.

Unfortunately it doesn't work in Rust yet (at least if you're using `wasm-bindgen` which you probably are) because wasm-bindgen discards all the DWARF info. See [this post](https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2020/11/30/how-to-wasm-dwarf/) and [this linked issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1981).